# Convert String to 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am currently receiving data from a client computer in the form of a string but I want it as a 2D array which is [25,3]. So I split it off into a single array first then tried to split that single array into a 2D array. However when I run the code I keep seeing an empty array anyone know why?

```
private void ClientReceiveData(object sender, ConnectedClient.NetDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
    {
        if (e.ID == 0)
        {
            result = Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(new[] { ',', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), Double.Parse);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {

                resultarray2D[i % 3, i % 3] = result[i];
                Trace.WriteLine(resultarray2D);
            }
        }

        if (e.ID == 1)
        {
            answer = Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(new[] { ',', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), Double.Parse); 
            for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
            {
                answerarray2D[i % 3, i / 3] = answer[i];
                Trace.WriteLine(answerarray2D);
            }
        }
```

Output: 
[image: Output]

Comment: You arent seeing an empty array, you are seeing [exactly what `.ToString()` on an array outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2).  If you want to see the contents of an array you have to access the individual values by index

Comment: `ConvertAll` does not work with multi-dimentions. Give us a single line of input, so we can judge what you're doing. And why do you use `mod` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (I made some changes to what the person above said and implemented it in your code):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message) == false)
        {

            if (e.ID == 0)
            {
                result = Array.ConvertAll(e.Message.Split(new[] { ',', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), Double.Parse);


                for (int x = 0; x < result.Length; x++)
                {

                    resultarray2D[x / 3, x % 3] = result[x];
                }
                int rowLength = resultarray2D.GetLength(0);
                int colLength = resultarray2D.GetLength(1);

                for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ", resultarray2D[i, j]));
                    }
                     Trace.WriteLine("\n");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I keep seeing an empty array

No, you see what the default output of `ToString` on an array is, which is the name of the class.  If you want to see the *contents* of the array, you ned to loop through and output the individual items:

```
int rowLength = arr.GetLength(0);
int colLength = arr.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", arr[i, j]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```